# C++ How to check first input of a multiple input statement?

Tags: c++, loops, input, while-loop

Here is the code:

```
while (productNumber != 0)
    {
        cin >> productNumber >> amount;
        item.Initialize(productNumber, description, price, taxable);
        item = list.GetItem(item, found);
    }
```

I have more code than that but I believe that is sufficient for the problem let me know if it is not. The objective is to exit the while loop without entering in amount. For example I want the user to be able to enter the productNumber then space then the amount then enter. I want the user to be able to do this multiple times which works fine. However, the moment the user presses 0 then enter I want the loop to quit without having to press another 0 and enter again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are initializing an object with functions, not with constructors. And what is up with list.getItem? Is that line important for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take the inputs in two steps then.

Replace

`cin >> productNumber >> amount;`

with

```
cin >> productNumber;

if(productNumber == 0) break;

cin >> amount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be improved as follows.

```
cin >> productNumber; // first read product number
while (productNumber != 0)
{
    cin >> amount; // read corresponding amount.
    item.Initialize(productNumber, description, price, taxable);
    item = list.GetItem(item, found);
    cin >> productNumber; // read product number again
}
```